# Wordpress: When I click in search results, it gives 404

Tags: wordpress

And thanks for your help!

I'm using Wordpress, with WPSearch plugin + elementor custom search page, the problem is:

When the results are displayed, it works flawlessly, but the URl from the title is wrong, and when you click on the the text you get redirected to the main page (I activated 404 errors to be redirected to mainpage). I can't find where to edit those links in search, anyone has any idea?

In cpanel "errors" I can see these:

```
[Fri Aug 20 19:21:12.443992 2021] [:error] [pid 580957:tid 23099625621248] [client XXX:15408] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505272.3485751152038574218750
[Fri Aug 20 19:20:53.445562 2021] [:error] [pid 580956:tid 23099634026240] [client XXX:15364] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505253.3393890857696533203125
[Fri Aug 20 19:20:27.565196 2021] [:error] [pid 580957:tid 23099755898624] [client XXX:5056] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7
[Fri Aug 20 19:20:02.575672 2021] [:error] [pid 580956:tid 23099600406272] [client XXX:15268] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505202.4825611114501953125000
[Fri Aug 20 19:18:52.393628 2021] [:error] [pid 580957:tid 23099585697536] [client XXX:15122] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505132.2978270053863525390625
[Fri Aug 20 19:18:05.437396 2021] [:error] [pid 580956:tid 23099568887552] [client XXX:15056] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505085.3480589389801025390625
[Fri Aug 20 19:17:09.918235 2021] [:error] [pid 580957:tid 23099755898624] [client XXX:12736] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7
[Fri Aug 20 19:17:06.951470 2021] [:error] [pid 580956:tid 23099720177408] [client XXX:17024] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7
[Fri Aug 20 19:16:55.437002 2021] [:error] [pid 580954:tid 23099638228736] [client XXX:14866] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1629505015.3463969230651855468750
[Fri Aug 20 19:16:41.682702 2021] [:error] [pid 580957:tid 23099688658688] [client XXX:1038] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/search/condolencias
[Fri Aug 20 19:16:39.020203 2021] [:error] [pid 580958:tid 23099730683648] [client XXX:30395] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in XXXpublic_html/php.ini on line 7, referer: XXX/search/condolencias
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. Look in your `public_html/php.ini` file. There is a `(` on line 7 that it doesn't expect. Which usually means something before it didn't get closed properly. Post the first 7 lines of your php.ini file here.

Comment: It's not your WordPress and plugin issue, it's your basic configuration issue. like .ini etc..